# How to get specific data that is present in an anchor tag

Tags: c#

I have downloaded a json data from an url and deserializing it to a class.

```
 expense = wc.DownloadString(url);
 Rec obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rec>(expense);
```

The class is,

```
public class Rec
    {
        public string BillNo { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

The 'BillNo' is in anchor format. I need loop through each rows to get specific values from the anchor tag. The anchor tag is like mentioned below.

```
<a name="429" href="/pw/moneyout/vendor_detail.do?entityID=4090&action=ViewBill&recentItem=true&tabIndex=4&vendorLedgerView.month=3&vendorLedgerView.year=2016&itemID=877560220&ReportEntityID=6683">429</a>
```

From the above anchor tag i need the itemId value '877560220' and the inner text '429'. How to accomplish it in c#.

Comment: Perhaps using a parsing library? https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Once you have the anchor element you could use a regex to extract the values - https://regex101.com/r/iW8aR8/1.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have got it to work.

Comment: @Ean See here for an example of the regex - https://repl.it/CJGV

Comment: @James Buck Thanks. It seems to be very useful.